# Resharper long Pending time

Tags: c#, resharper, nunit-3.0

I have a project with > 8k tests. Recently i've updated the Resharper and NUnit to latest versions but the Pending time visible increased to ~1.5 minutes.
Any ideas why this is happening?
I've attached an image with the two states.
[image]